# identityserver4 with redux -oidc client requested access token - but client is not configured to receive access tokens via browser

Tags: redux, react-redux, identityserver4, redux-thunk, redux-saga

My identityserver4 client looks like this:

```
new Client {
    ClientId = "openIdConnectClient",
    ClientName = "Example Implicit Client Application",
    //AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
    ClientSecrets =
    {
       new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 30,
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "role",
        "customAPI.write"
    },
    RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:8080/callback"},
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"https://localhost:44330"},
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
     {
         "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
         "http://localhost:8080",
         "*"
     },
}
```

In react application, my userManager class looks like this:

```
 import { createUserManager } from 'redux-oidc';

const userManagerConfig = {
  client_id: 'openIdConnectClient',
  redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ''}/callback`,
  //response_type: 'code id_token token',
  response_type: 'token id_token',
  scope: 'openid profile email role',
  authority: 'http://localhost:50604',
  silent_redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ''}/silent_renew.html`,
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true,
};

const userManager = createUserManager(userManagerConfig);

export default userManager;
```

The question is: when i try to call my identityserver4 from the redux-oidc example application. I'm getting the following error:

> Client requested access token - but client is not configured to receive access tokens via browser

I hope you understood the question. Please someone help me with this. i have provided the link for this example application bellow.

[Redux-oidc example app link](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example)

Comment: nevermind, i found the issue, there is a table in the DB called dbo.Clients which is created by identityServer4. you have to change the AllowAccessTokenViaBrowser column value to true

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code contains two different grant types.  The different [Grant types](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html) in Identity server 4 have different requirements.  Here is a bit of information to help you understand the different types you are using.  It may also help you understand why you were having this problem.

**GrantTypes.ClientCredentials**

The Client credentials is the simplest grant type and is used for server to server communication - tokens are always requested on behalf of a client, not a user.

With this grant type you send a token request to the token endpoint, and get an access token back that represents the client. The client typically has to authenticate with the token endpoint using its client ID and secret.

```
new Client
    {
        ClientId = "client",

        // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

        // secret for authentication
        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },

        // scopes that client has access to
        AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
    }
```

**GrantTypes.Implicit**

The implicit grant type is optimized for browser-based applications. Either for user authentication-only (both server-side and JavaScript applications), or authentication and access token requests (JavaScript applications).

In the implicit flow, all tokens are transmitted via the browser, and advanced features like refresh tokens are thus not allowed. If you want to transmit access tokens via the browser channel, you also need to allow that explicitly on the client configuration:

```
Client.AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true;


 new Client
    {
        ClientId = "mvc",
        ClientName = "MVC Client",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

        // where to redirect to after login
        RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },

        // where to redirect to after logout
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

        AllowedScopes = new List<string>
        {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
        },
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
    }
```

Comment: yes, your solution is correct. i changed my code to implicit flow and i had to change the AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser column value to true. it wasn't working because even though, i added 'AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true' in my code, it didn't change the db table value. so now all good! thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you have been following the Identity server 4 documentation but i just submitted a pull.  The Implicit sample was missing AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser